# AJAX partial DOM posting with link_to_remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I tried to send some field values of DOM using link_to, but they are not transmitted well. Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

form.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :a_place, {id: 'a_place'} %>
<%= f.text_field :occ_place, {id: 'occ_place'} %>
<%= link_to "Search", getlatlng_path, :submit=>"occ_place", method: :post, :class => "btn btn-success" %>
```

I want to pass only a_place and occ_place to controller.

reports_controller.rb

```
def latlng
  query = params[:occ_place]
  url = ""
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
  $items = doc.xpath('//item').map do |i|
    { :title => i.xpath('title').inner_text,
      :address => i.xpath('address').inner_text, 
      :mapx => i.xpath('mapx').inner_text,
      :mapy => i.xpath('mapy').inner_text
    }
  end
```

end

routes.rb

```
match '/getlatlng', to: 'reports#latlng', via: 'post'
```

Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What're params that your controller has received ?, see them from server.

Comment: @MohamedYakot How could I check params from server?

Comment: Check the terminal. You can also look at the log files under the logs folder.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use something like the pry gem, which gives you a REPL for debugging.